# Julia Plot Log colorscale

Tags: plot, julia, surface

Im trying to build a 3D surface plot with color in log10 scale in `julia` using `plot` function. I just want the color to be in the log10 scale NOT the actual values itself.

```
using Plots
N = 51
x = range(-10, stop = 10, length = N)
y = x
f(x,y)=x^2+y^2
Plots.plot(x,y,f,st=:surface,color=:jet,camera=(25,65))
```

Below is the output.

[image]

Below is the same function that was created using `GNUPLOT` with logscale in color. How would you create the chart in `Julia` using plot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Colors` support palettes with `logscale=true` parameter, for an example:

```
using Colors

Plots.plot(x,y,f,st=:surface,color=Colors.diverging_palette(20,300,20, logscale=true,  wcolor=colorant"red",dcolor1=colorant"green", dcolor2=colorant"red", b=0.1,d1=1.0,d2=1.0),camera=(25,65))
```

[image]